# How do I use mockito to throw HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized error

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, exception, mockito

I am using mockito to mock my `authenticationService.getUserInfo` method.

I am having difficulty in try to mock `HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized`.

I can't just new `HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized`.

Is there any other way?

Implementation:

```
try {
    result = authenticationService.getUserInfo(accessToken);

} catch (HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized e) {

    String errorMsg = "Invalid access token - " + e.getMessage();

    throw new InvalidAccessTokenException(errorMsg);
}
```

Test case:

```
@Test
public void givenInvalidToken_whenGetUserInfoThrows401Response_thenThrowInvalidAccessTokenExceptionAndFail() throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpClientErrorException ex = new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);

    exceptionRule.expect(InvalidAccessTokenException.class);
    exceptionRule.expectMessage("Invalid access token - " + ex.getMessage());

    Mockito.when(authenticationService.getUserInfo(anyString())).thenThrow(ex);

    filter.doFilterInternal(this.request, this.response, this.mockChain);
}
```

Error logs from running test case:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: (an instance of com.demo.security.common.exception.InvalidAccessTokenException and exception with message a string containing "Invalid access token - 401 UNAUTHORIZED")
     but: an instance of com.demo.security.common.exception.InvalidAccessTokenException <org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 UNAUTHORIZED> is a org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException
Stacktrace was: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 UNAUTHORIZED
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized.html) is child exception of [HttpStatusCodeException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/HttpClientErrorException.html)

```
public static final class HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized
extends HttpClientErrorException
```

So when you throw `HttpStatusCodeException` the catch block will not executed since child exception will not catch parent exception.

So create `HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized` and throw it

```
HttpClientErrorException http = HttpClientErrorException.Unauthorized.create(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, null, null, null, null);
```

I would also recommend to catch `HttpStatusCodeException` since `UNAUTHORIZED` is specific to `401` and any 400 series exceptions will not be caught by `UNAUTHORIZED`. You can also get status code from `HttpClientErrorException` and verify it as shown in my answer

```
try {

result = authenticationService.getUserInfo(accessToken);

} catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {

if(e.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
  //do something

String errorMsg = "Invalid access token - " + e.getMessage();

throw new InvalidAccessTokenException(errorMsg);
}
```

Comment: So does this means that all i need to do is to catch the parent class i.e. `HttpClientErrorException` at my implementation level??

Comment: yes and you can get the status code from `HttpClientErrorException` and verify status code @shadow